# angular2 : read a file from local machine

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi I am new to JavaScript and Angular 2.

**I want to read a text file from local machine and show the content on page**. I have the file in assets folder. How can I read it using typescript?

Thanks in advance :)

I tried passing file path as `"e"` but the error i am getting is on `files[0]`. If I remove `files[0]` error I am getting is `parameter 1` is not of type `'Blob'`.

```
private readSingleFile(e) {
    var fileName = e.files[0];
    console.log(fileName);
    if (!fileName) {
      return;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = file => {
      var contents: any = file.target;
      this.text = contents.result;
    };
    reader.readAsText(fileName);
    console.log(reader.readAsText(fileName))
}
```

Comment: use e.target.files  u pass $event to readSingleFile from html

Answer (score 4):

instead of e.files[0]
try

> e.target.files[0]

code snippet:

```
 var fileName = e.target.files[0];

 <input type='file' (change)='readSingleFile($event)'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the responses.

Finally i read the files using 'ng2-file-upload' and uploaded them to server also.